# Cubemap skybox from the scene of the shader

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader, textures, skybox

Problem, perhaps, simple:
I can't figure out how to get the skybox and apply it to my shader.

I think I'm close but how do I take the skybox from the scene??

```
mygameobjec.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.SetTexture("_SkyReflection",Skybox.material.Texture??);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try RenderSettings.skybox.mainTexture.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RenderSettings-skybox.html

A tip though: it is also possible to access the current reflection environment inside the shader from a shader global called unity_SpecCube0. Here is a function i often use in my shaders:

```
// Returns the reflection color given a normal and view direction.
inline half3 SurfaceReflection(half3 viewDir, half3 worldNormal, half roughness) {

    half3 worldRefl = reflect(-viewDir, worldNormal);
    half r = roughness * 1.7 - 0.7 * roughness;
    float4 reflData = UNITY_SAMPLE_TEXCUBE_LOD(
        unity_SpecCube0, worldRefl, r * 6
    );

    return DecodeHDR (reflData, unity_SpecCube0_HDR);
}
```